# Python invalid Syntax Error at while line 7

Tags: python-2.7

```
def main():
        print "This Program will calculate the amount of parking charges by hours using a     given list: "
        ticket = raw_input("Please enter ticket. If lost, Please enter no")
        if ticket in ['No','no','N','n']
        hour = float(input("Enter total hour at parking deck: ")          
        while(hour <= 0 or hour > 24):
        hour = int(input("Enter an integer between 1-24 (hour): "))
```

The code above has a syntax error at line 6 at the word while

Comment: Pay attention to what the interpreter tells you.  It's not just a `SyntaxError`, it's an `IndentationError`.  If that doesn't tell you what's wrong...

Comment: In my python code, I did indent correctly; however, it states that the while has an invalid Syntax

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams haha.  Okay, right, fooled by the "error at the word while..."

Comment: You are missing a `:` in the `if` statement and a closing brace `)` in the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bracket/brace missing in the below line.  Add the brace and the error should go away.

```
hour = float(input("Enter total hour at parking deck: ")
```

Also the if needs a colon at the end. Below are the corrected lines

```
if ticket in ['No','no','N','n']:
    hour = float(input("Enter total hour at parking deck: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Statements that start a new block such as `if` and `while` need a semicolon at the end.

```
if ...:
 ...
while ...:
 ...
```

And their blocks need to be indented one level as well.